# Any experience of using PostSharp with ReSharper

Tags: resharper, postsharp

Has anyone used PostSharp with ReSharper, if so what problems should I expect?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I use Resharper when developing PostSharp. I also use Resharper when working on customer projects using PostSharp. There are no significant problems.

As for recommendations done by Resharper, remember that they are done based on an analysis of the source code, and are not aware of aspects.

Comment: I use Reshaper with PostSharp too and have not had problems related to Resharpe with it.